# Ubuntu 22.04LTS - Wifi issue low network speed because of IPv6

Tags: networking, 22.04, ipv6

I upgrade from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04LTS. I noticed that my wifi speed slowed down from 40 Mbps to 1 Mbps(max) after one hour. Again, if I reboot then it worked fine.
After trying multiple suggestions online, one that worked for me:

Go into Wifi Setting and disable IPv6(Default is automatic).

Is there any other way to fix this IPv6 issue?

Comment: This is the ISP issue, ask them

Comment: @Pilot6 I am using the dual boot, everything is fine in windows 11. Do you mean that my router automatically switches to IPV6 when possible & IPv6 is having issue because of ISP end ?

Comment: IPV6 is default. But many ISPs have problems with it.